# Mapping devices in a pool to physical drives

Tags: mount, nas

I'm setting up a Ubuntu NAS by repurposing a PC, and decided to go with the ZFS file system. I'd like to map the devices in a pool to physical drives (6 identical 12TB drives), so that I know which to swap out later. Never performed such an operation so not sure how best to accomplish this best. Can I plug in all the drives at the same time, and somehow mount them in turn? If so, how do I distinguish which physical drive is being mounted? Or do I need to plug them in one by one, labeling which drive I plugged in, and mount it before shutting down and plugging another drive in? Would that guarantee that the unique drive (not one of its 5 twins) gets mounted as that device next time?